# Interlinear glossing and small caps for sites like Russian Language and Usage

Tags: feature-request, markdown

It is a common notational convention in linguistics to use small capitals in [interlinear glossing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss). Using good ol' plain capitals for that is almost like *not* using the `[code][/code]` tag for code snippets. To quote Wikipedia,

> Grammatical terms are commonly abbreviated and printed in SMALL CAPITALS to keep them distinct from translations, especially when they are frequent or important for analysis.

For example, the following phrase in [Tigrinya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigrinya_language) could be glossed as follows:

> ʔab ʔasmɐra tɐ-wɐlɐd-ku
>   *in Asmara PASS-bear.PERF-1SG.PERF*
>   ‘I was born in Asmara’

Seeing as we already have sites dedicated to languages other than English (and even Linguistics.SE), while the [*Russian Language & Usage*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language-usage) Q&A (where interlinear glossing would be useful due to the highly [inflectional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) nature of the language) is on track to being launched, would it be possible to implement a small-caps variant or even a full-blown [HTML glossing](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-do-i-format-an-interlinear-gloss-for-html) feature?

(Of course, the latter would be preferable because ideally words and their tiered annotations align vertically, but that could be too much work, I don't know.)